# PHP imagick no decode delegate for large files

Tags: php, imagick

I'm facing an unusual problem :-

When uploading and resizing images using imagick files greater than 1mb or so it returns Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format.

It returns the error at the point where it is trying to read the format.

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->readImage($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); /* this is where it boots me out*/
```

For example if I take a an image and resize in photoshop so small.jpg is 1mb and large.jpg is 2mb.

small.jp will upload and resize fine but large.jpg will fail with the above error.

This is the same for all formats (png/gif etc).

From PHP INFO
magick module version   3.1.2
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16

Comment: Try checking the error code in `$_FILES['file']['error']` [see file upload doumentation in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) Then check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in the php.ini

Comment: It's possible the file size is probably irrelevant. "No decode delegate" means that ImageMagick doesn't know how to read that image type. Check that is able to read it by running the code through a command line script first.

Comment: Thats what I was getting at i.e. and empty temp file might cause that situation

Comment: cheers it was upload_max_filesize